# Divs don't get inline after adding text

Tags: html, css

Why do the divs not go inline after adding text into the content div inside the inline divs? Is it a bug?
Here I added my code. I tried with  with jfiddle. But no solution yet.

```
<div style="display:block">
<div style="width:230px; color:#000; background-color:#EAEAEA; border-radius:6px;display:inline-block; ">
    <div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px;" class="font">
        Colombo City
    </div>
    <div style="width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(images/colombo.png);margin:14px;">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:14px;word-wrap:break-word;width:202px;height:200px;background-color:#0099CC;">
        add more textadd more textadd more textadd more textadd more textadd more text
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:230px; color:#000; background-color:#EAEAEA; border-radius:6px; display:inline-block;margin-left:3px; ">
    <div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px;" class="font">
        Great Sigiriya
    </div>
    <div style="width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(images/sigiriya.png);margin:14px;">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:14px;word-wrap:break-word;width:202px;height:200px;background-color:#0099CC;">
        Colombo
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:230px; color:#000; background-color:#EAEAEA; border-radius:6px;display:inline-block;margin-left:3px; ">
    <div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px;" class="font">
        YALA National Park
    </div>
    <div style="width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(images/hillcountry.png);margin:14px;">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:14px;word-wrap:break-word;width:202px;height:200px;background-color:#0099CC;">
        Colombo
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:230px; color:#000;  background-color:#EAEAEA; border-radius:6px; display:inline-block;margin-left:3px;">
    <div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px;" class="font">
        Arts & Crafts
    </div>
    <div style="width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(images/crafts.png);margin:14px;">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:14px;word-wrap:break-word;width:202px;height:200px;background-color:#0099CC;">
        Colombo
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KABHH/
Here it is from jfiddle

Comment: ew.  why not use CSS?  aside from that, what exactly is the problem?  Have you given the container enough of a width to actually fit all your elements?  http://jsfiddle.net/KABHH/1/

Comment: use a CSS stylesheet, this is horrable to read. Not that it has to do anything with your problem but it gives you a better view then inline style

Comment: this much of inline css ?

Comment: Dont recomend creating a stylesheet, you dont know if those parameters are static or dynamic, and you can pass parameters on css. People need to stop assuming everyone who work on web development, make only sites.

Comment: Ok now I added CSS..But the problem still same
http://jsfiddle.net/KABHH/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't  use `inline-block` for every div just `float` them. It will do it for you.

```
  <div style="display:inline-block">
   <div class="mainsquare">
   <div class="font titlesquare">Colombo City</div>
   <div class="imagesquare1"></div>
   <div class="contentsquare">Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo Colombo </div>
   </div>

   <div class="mainsquare left">
   <div  class="font titlesquare">Great Sigiriya</div>
   <div class="imagesquare2"></div>
   <div class="contentsquare">Colombo    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="mainsquare left">
   <div class="font titlesquare">Colombo City</div>
   <div class="imagesquare1"></div>
   <div class="contentsquare">Colombo </div>
   </div>

   <div class="mainsquare left">
   <div  class="font titlesquare">Great Sigiriya</div>
   <div class="imagesquare2"></div>
   <div class="contentsquare">Colombo</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And css

```
.mainsquare{
 width:230px; color:#000; background-color:#EAEAEA; border-radius:6px;
 float:left;
}
.titlesquare{
  text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center; 
   background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px;
}

.contentsquare{
  margin:14px;word-wrap:break-word;width:202px;height:200px;
   background-color:#0099CC;
 }

.imagesquare1{
   width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(../images/colombo.png);
    margin:14px;
 }

.imagesquare2{
  width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(../images/sigiriya.png);
   margin:14px;
 }

.imagesquare3{
  width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(../images/hillcountry.png);
    margin:14px;
 }

.imagesquare4{
  width:202px;height:202px;background-image:url(../images/crafts.png);
    margin:14px;
 }
.left{
  margin-left:3px;
 }
 }
```

Take a look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KABHH/5/)**.

**Tip**

> **You should not be using inline-css for the same css again and again. make a css class and call it where ever you want**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing

`<div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px; display:inline;" class="font">Colombo City</div>`

?? Seems like you want these divs inline so why aren't they having that style?
Besides the best woud  be
`<div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:14px;color:#000000;text-align:center;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:6px;padding:5px; float:left;" class="font">Colombo City</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that by default the CSS `display` property is not an inherited property (i.e. the `display: inline-block` does not cascade down to child elements).

If you want to set the display on the parent and inherit on the children then you need to add:

```
display: inherit;
```

on the child divs.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you could try using the below on your divs.

```
float: left;
```

I would also suggest using a stylesheet rather than the horrible inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

they won't get 'inline' .. they are BLOCKS. **Just float them left** will force em back to the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `float: left` to your second div:

```
<div style="width:230px; color:#000; background-color:#EAEAEA; border-radius:6px;display:inline-block;float:left ">
```

and they lined up!

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KABHH/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the 2 good suggestions you got here: (1) use floats; (2) use a stylesheet.

But just so you know why it doesn't align, you need to add:

```
vertical-align: top
```

to each div that is inline-block. The reason is that the height varies. Read more here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QKNg8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to each one of the four `div`s inside your main div (the first one, `<div style="display:block">`)